# login using post request in scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I want to login rediffmail but error is generate

> exceptions.NameError: global name 'FormRequest' is not defined

here my spider code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from rediffmail.items import RediffmailItem
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'rediffmail'
    allowed_domains    = ["rediff.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://mail.rediff.com/cgi-bin/login.cgi']

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'login': 'XXXX', 'passwd': 'XXXX'},callback=self.after_login)]     

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return
```

Please check is there any issue in my code. I am beginner in python

Comment: If i use this "return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'login': 'XXXX', 'passwd': 'XXXX'},callback=self.after_login)" is also given error "exceptions.AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FormRequest'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the import of `FormRequest`. And in your version of scrapy, the `FormRequest` is in `scrapy.http`.

So add this line in your import section:

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
```